# PTIJ: How can we have extra simcha when the trees are brought in if the tree is too big to move?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The gemara says in Taanit (29a):

> מִשֶּׁנִּכְנַס אדר מַרְבִּין בְּשִׂמְחָה.

When *adar* comes in, we increase simcha.

What is an *adar*?

If we look at other places where the same word is used, we find this in Beitzah (15b):

> וְאָמַר רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן מִשּׁוּם רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר בְּרַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן: הָרוֹצֶה שֶׁיִּתְקַיְּימוּ נְכָסָיו — יִטַּע בָּהֶן אדר, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״אַדִּיר בַּמָּרוֹם ה׳״.
>
> One who wants his properties to be preserved and protected from ruin should plant an eder tree among them, as it is stated: "The Lord on high is mighty [adir]"

Rashi there explains that "adar" is a prominent tree, which everybody knows is on your property, so your property will be safe from adverse possession (squatters) because everybody knows that you have an adar tree.

It can be assumed part of the prominence of the tree is its size and longevity. If that is the case, it clearly cannot be brought into the house.

So how can a person increase happiness in the house if it is impossible to move the tree?

---

Bonus image:

[image: the Lorax]

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Note that the question doesn't begin according to the second explanation in Rashi there, that אדר is a type of grass.

Comment: @Meir do you have grass growing in your house?

Answer (score 5):

One is supposed to build a treehouse inside the Adar tree. Once this is completed he goes into the treehouse משנכנס אדר and adds Simcha.

This is to remember the miracle of Haman being hung from a tree.

Comment: Good answer! I always wanted a treehouse when I was a kid.